# Explicitly set a cell’s datatype as text for number values

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to explicitly set a cell’s datatype as a text for number values.

I am fetching data from my MySQL database and exporting to excel file using PHPExcel Library. I have large about 20 digit long numbers which I want to export to excel cell(each cell of the entire column will have different numbers).

I have found that you can do this by code mentioned PHPExcel Documentation 4.6.7.

```
$i=0;
foreach($dd as $d) {
    $objPHPExcel
        ->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
       ->getcell('A'.$i)
       ->setValueExplicit($d['serial_no'], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $i++;
}
```

`$d['serial_no']`-different serials coming from database e.g."9876543211234567890".

I have implemented this code its working fine. But when I open that excel sheet and try to modify that cell then click on anywhere else it again gets converted to number format(client's requirement: it should remain as text).

I want to stay that cell as text even if I edit in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPExcel - set cell type before writing a value in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143236/phpexcel-set-cell-type-before-writing-a-value-in-it)

Comment: thanks that was solution

Comment: The problem there lies with MS Excel, not with PHPExcel

Comment: thanks for reply, solved by answer mentioned in @SiimKallari comment, i think i should have declare type before writing a value in cell. Also thank for great library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not tested it, but possibly setting the cell as "quotePrefix" may prevent MS Excel from trying to convert the datatype when editing it with MS Excel

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A2:O128')
    ->setQuotePrefix(true);
```

Excel2007 only

Comment: do I have to add this with `setValueExplicit()`

Comment: Use the `setValueExplicit()` to set the cell's value as string (the default) then set the cell style as quotePrefix true

Answer (score 6):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A'.$i)
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(
    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
);
```