# PHPOFFICESPREEDSHEET CELL FORMAT

Tags: php, excel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I am using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet to generate a .csv file. I have a number in a cell but I want the number to be formatted as text so no formulas apply to the cell. The problem is that the number eg `58` I should put as `'58` and excel should automatically convert that to text. (That cell should have a green triangle at the top left and the `'` before the number should not be visible in that cell-Can be seen in the Formula bar.) However the cell shows the number as I put it(`'58`) and this makes the file invalid. My current code is

```
$spreadsheet = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
.......
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', "'58");
......
$sheet->getStyle('A2:K' . $sheet->getHighestRow())
      ->getAlignment()
      ->setHorizontal(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
$sheet->getStyle('A2:F' . $sheet->getHighestRow())
      ->getNumberFormat()
      ->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
.....
$writer = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('file_name.xlsx');
```

What might I be doing wrong?

What my code produces:

[image: image 1]

What I expect:

[image: image 2]

Comment: @Solar The generated file has `'58' in the cell unless the user goes clicking cell by cell for it to be correct. (Just double clicking the cell alone)

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086293/explicitly-set-a-cell-s-datatype-as-text-for-number-values?

Comment: @user3783243 is that linked answer for excel files or csv?

Comment: @SolarMike Look to be Excel, there's not mention of CSV there

Comment: @user but the OP wants a csv file so how does that help resolve the issue?

Comment: @SolarMike They want a XSL file that is CSV formatted. `$writer->save('file_name.xlsx');`

Comment: user3783243 either CSV or XLSX is okay as long as the sheet is like in image 2 above

Comment: @Stevooh Had you seen linked thread before, or did it help?

Comment: @user3783243 I have seen the thread but it doesn't work yet