# How to set PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING in krajee yii2-export

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I meet a problem - when I export excel by Krajee yii2-export it will change long number to scientific notation in which lost last two bits.
For example 201210171530 will be 2.012E+12, when I click it, 2.012E+12 will display as 201210171500. The last two bit '30' is lost,because '30' change to be '00'

How can I fix it? Or where can I set the cell datatype?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel - set cell type before writing a value in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143236/phpexcel-set-cell-type-before-writing-a-value-in-it)

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit PHP or a 64-bit PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a way.
I add prefixion '.
any good method?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsmtM.png)

Answer (score 0):

when your export successfull, you must open your excel
and then you block the number metric and then, right click the block
choose Format Data, and then click Number, and OK

Comment: If I do that,I will lost the last two bit.It