# How to convert string "3.82384E+11" to BIGINT with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I'm trying to save some ID values from CSV that are automatically converted to exponent numbers by Excel.

Like `382383816413` becomes `3.82384E+11`. So I'm doing a full import into my MySQL database with:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
  'file.csv'
INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@`item_id`,
@`colum2`,
@`colum3`)

SET
  item_id = @`item_id`;
```

I've tried using cast like:

`CAST('3.82384E+11' as UNSIGNED)` and it gives me just `3`.

`CAST('3.82384E+11' as BIGINT)` and it doesn't work.

`CAST('3.82384E+11' as UNSIGNED BIGINT)` and gives me `3` again.

So, what's the better way to convert string exponent numbers to real big integers in MySQL?

Comment: This is an [Excel problem](https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel). Once the CSV data is mangled there's no easy fix. Excel's exponential notation often discards data.

Comment: _"Like `382383816413` becomes `3.82384E+11`"_ - you're aware that information has already been lost at this point, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My option was to convert the column with `3.82384E+11` to number in the excel file, so it get back to the original value. Then I export to CSV and use SQL query to import it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set column format as text instead of number in excel. Refer below link.

[PHPExcel - set cell type before writing a value in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143236/phpexcel-set-cell-type-before-writing-a-value-in-it)